# How do I convert topics for each item in the dataset into a feature vector, considering that each item can have more than 1 topic

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a dataset which contains english statements. Each statement has been assigned a number of topics that the statement is about. The topics could be economy, sports, politics, business, science, etc. Each statement can have more than 1 topic. Some statements can have 1 topic, some can have 2 topics, so on and so forth. For the statement itself I am using TF-IDF vectors to convert statement into a feature vector. However, I am confused how to convert topics into a feature vector for machine learning training.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a binary column for each topic which will show whether the statement has this topic.